# Does ether transfer consume all gas in case of exception?

Tags: exceptions, address.transfer, revert-opcode

If `addr.transfer()` fails, does it use a `revert`- or `throw`-style exception? In other words, does a failed `transfer` consume all provided gas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it won't consume all of the gas provided.

Whilst [as per the documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=transfer#global-variables) it will throw:

```
<address>.transfer(uint256 amount): send given amount of Wei to Address, throws on failure
```

Since the ["REVERT instruction" EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/206) it looks like not all of the gas is consumed anymore.

---

To test this, I created some simple contracts - that can be seen on [this EthFiddle](https://ethfiddle.com/5VI0xBiQPV).

I deployed the contracts using remix and called the `forward` function of my `Transfer` contract and despite the transaction using Remix's default of 3,000,000 gas the actual gas cost was 29,135:

[image]

Debugging the transaction, and looking at the stack, I can see that the reasonably recently added REVERT OPCODE was called:

[image]

Which I believe accounts for not all of the gas being consumed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, when `address.transfer()` fails it throws an exception and reverts any state changes.

**Edit to clarify my original answer**

[As per the documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions), when a `.transfer()` fails it throws a require-style exception, which will revert any state changes. Require-style exceptions will not consume any gas.

Comment: I think that this answer is out of date - see my answer for my research into how changes to the EVM have altered the behavior upon exceptions being thrown.

Comment: @SteveJaxon why is this answer out-of-date? As Shaun mentioned, when `address.transfer()` fails it throws require-style exception. As mentioned in [Solidity Docs Error handling](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions). IMO this answer might be incomplete, but not out of date.

Comment: The question was "Does ether transfer consume all gas in case of exception?" - you answered "yes, ...". This was correct a year ago, but I don't think that it is true anymore.

Comment: I can see how that might be confusing. I was answering this portion of the question: If addr.transfer() fails, does it use a revert- or throw-style exception? The answer is yes, it does revert, as per the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)